# Applying Stokes' theorem

Tags: integration, vector-analysis

$C$ is the surface $z=y(e^{-x^2}-y-1/2)$ and conditions $z\geq 0$, $x \in [-1, 1]$ and $\varphi = dxdz+dydz+(e^{-x^2}-2y-1/2)xe^{xz}dxdy$ is a 2-form.

I have to compute $\int_C\varphi$ using Stokes' theorem. I have already computed the integral using common technique and got $0$, but the problem is I must do it with Stokes.

However I can't understand how, because $\varphi$ is not exact, so I can't find a form $\psi$ such that $d\psi=\varphi$. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated properly? It seems you want $C$ to be the boundary curve of the surface based on how you've written this.

Comment: Yes I am sure. How could I take an integral of a 2-form if $C$ was not 2-dimensional?

Comment: Isn't this surface a boundary of something 3-dimensional, such as $z\leq y(\ldots )$? I don't see it but if yes, you might use Stokes..

Comment: This surface is not. But i guess i could add something to it so it became a boundary of a 3-dimensional body. But then some more integrals should appear..

Comment: You couldn't, but the way you were describing the problem makes it seem that way, since if you're right and it's not exact, then there is no way to apply Stokes, since it requires you do $\int_{\partial M}\omega =\int_M \mathrm{d}\omega$. If there is no such function, then you cannot switch to the boundary of your surface. I haven't had the chance to check exactness for myself yet, though, so maybe the problem is there.

Comment: @AdamHughes There is still a way to apply Stokes, if $C$ were the boundary of something 3-dimensional (or could be simply completed to a boundary by adding another surgace). In fact, I don't see any other option.

Comment: @PeterFranek Yes, thanks, I know. :-) I am taking on faith (for the moment) that he's right that it's not the boundary of anything, since there are a lot of things to check, and I'm eliminating one at a time.

Comment: @PeterFranek I could reflect $C$ with respect to $Oxy$ and these 2 halves may make something which may be a boundary. Still have to check that though.

Comment: @Elensil, nope, I just graphed it using some software, it doesn't have a boundary on any plane. :/

Comment: @AdamHughes What if we take $-C$ surface? I mean $z=-y(e^{-x^2}-y-1/2)$ with $z \leq 0$.

Comment: @Elensil that's the same thing as the original, just upside down so it doesn't really help. I've got to say, you should ask whoever gave you the problem on this from the looks of it. There might be an error somewhere, but the usual tricks don't work, and this doesn't feel like any sort of special problem with a special trick to it. Is this the problem verbatim, without any changes in language or form?

Comment: But i meant actually adding $-C$ to $C$, so they together may make up a boundary. Then we maybe should have $\int_{-C}+\int_C=\int_D$, where $D$ is something 3-dimensional...

Comment: Unfortunately I am sure, this problem was printed for me...